# SELECT WHERE ... hundreds of conditions

Tags: sql, where-clause

Is there an elegant way to do this:

```
SELECT Cols from MyTable WHERE 
zip = 90210 OR
zip = 23310 OR
zip = 74245 OR
zip = 77427 OR
zip = 18817 OR
zip = 94566 OR
zip = 34533 OR
zip = 96322 OR
zip = 34566 OR
zip = 52214 OR
zip = 73455 OR
zip = 52675 OR
zip = 54724 OR
zip = 98566 OR
zip = 92344 OR
zip = 90432 OR
zip = 91532 OR
...
```

(zip codes in this post are ficticious and bear no resemblance to actual zip codes living or dead)

Answer (score 28):

Yes: Try this sql query.

```
Select cols from MyTable where zip in (90210, 23310, ... etc.)
```

Comment: Even better would be to store the ZIPs in a table and embed a select in the IN clause.

Comment: *Even* better would be to use a 'where exists' or a join instead of 'in'

Answer (score 17):

Depends on the definition of "elegant" :)

However, with that many ZIP codes, I think you might want to manage them in the DB too.

How do you decide which ZIP codes to match against?

So you could put the ZIP codes in a table of their own and do

```
SELECT cols FROM MyTable, ZipTable WHERE MyTable.zip = ZipTable.zip
```

Comment: I agree. This type of query is usually a sign that you are missing a table or a column, or you are trying to do what databases are there for: to join stuff.

Answer (score 10):

Or a combination of both, a nested query:

```
SELECT cols FROM MyTable WHERE zip IN 
    (SELECT zip FROM ZipTable WHERE condition=true)
```

Comment: In MySQL IN is less effective than EXISTS, so (if MySQL is used) it would be better to write: 
SELECT cols FROM MyTable M WHERE exists 
    (SELECT 1 FROM ZipTable Z WHERE M.ZIP=Z.ZIP and condition=true)

Answer (score 3):

I'd use something like:

- `start transaction;`
- `create temporary table if not exists ZIPS(ZIP integer) storage=memory;`
- `insert into ZIPS (ZIP) VALUES(...)`
- `select COLS from MYTABLE M, ZIPS Z where Z.ZIP = M.ZIP`
- `drop table ZIPS`  (or truncate it or do whatever you wish)
- either `commit` or `rollback`

In every db API you should have some variation of *executemany* function, which can call `insert into TABLE(COLUMNS) VALUES` with multiple value rows and be faster than repeating single insert. And you can wrap such call sequence in some function, for easy reuse, as a temporary table with one INT column is often handy :-)

This way you can avoid problem with maximum SQL query length problem (e.in g. MySQL) and your query is effective, clean and easy to maintain or extend further.

Answer (score 0):

With that many items you really should create a look-up table, especially if you need to search through them on a regular basis in other sections of code.  This will encapsulate your code which leads to easier edits if it is used in multiple functions and better reading aesthetics.

Example:
    --create table Lookups and fill column Values with your set of zip codes in this case

```
SELECT Cols 
FROM MyTable  
WHERE EXISTS (Select * FROM Lookups WHERE MyTable.zip = Lookups.values)
```

using JOIN

```
SELECT DISTINCT Cols
FROM MyTable JOIN
     Lookups ON MyTable.zip = Lookups.values
```

Comment: A simple join on the 2 tables will be easier to read, and it will give better performance in most cases. (Yes, the lookup table is a good idea!)